# Interact with DIV under another DIVs margin on the phone

Tags: html, css, mobile, web-applications, mobile-application

I want to build a simple web-app which displays a map and a list. The list should be over the map, and should be scrollable. The map should always stay at the same position, so that these two items act like layers.

I managed to build that purely with HTML/CSS and it works on the computer, but not on the phone (iPhone).

My code is the following:

```
    <style>
    html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .map {
        background-color: yellow;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    .list {
        height: 2000px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 200px;
        z-index: 1;
        color: white;
    }
    .layer {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="map">
            MAP
        </div>
        <div class="layer">
            <div class="list"><a href="#">
                LIST
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

I can interact with the map when I scroll down the list on the computer, but not on the phone. When I add the css-property `pointer-events: none;` to the layer-div, then I can't click on links in it (naturally). Even when I change the `margin-top` from the list-div to `top: 200px` it doesn't work (on the phone).

I also created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8g6A/) for that.

**EDIT** I made a picture with the Google Maps app. As you can see, the drawer can be drawn from bottom to top, but the Map itself **stays** in place, so both act like two layers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably this:

```
<body>
  <div class="map">
    MAP
  </div>
 <div class="list">
    LIST<br>LIST<br>LIST<br>LIST<br>LIST<br>LIST<br>LIST<br>LIST<br>LIST<br>LIST<br>LIST
 </div>
```

css:

```
html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .map {
        background-color: yellow;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .list {
        position:fixed;
        background-color: blue;
        top: 200px;
        bottom:0;
        left:20px;
        right:20px;
        z-index: 2;
        color: white;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j8g6A/1/

Comment: thank you, but i want that the list can be scrolled over the map (so the list should scroll to the top and further). like the google maps app does with the maps and the result drawer on the bottom (which can be dragged to the top)

Comment: ..so, instead of using top:200px; use top:0; ..?

Comment: but then i can't scroll the list to the bottom (so that it reveals the map and the user can interact with the map). i hope you know what i mean, it should act exactly like the google maps app with the drawer on the bottom

Comment: You can't get across what you need. A side drawer?

Comment: i updated my question with a picture. hope you know what i mean

Comment: Well, this is something completely different. You should create a fixed element at the bottom, and use transform translate to pull it upwards using a button..

Comment: hm, thanks, but it shouldn't just translate when i click a button. the user should be able to slide the drawer to the top/middle/whatever-position-he-wants of the screen, and the list should stay (at the position) with the (positioned fixed) map underneath. the list has 100 entries, so he should be able to scroll it and scroll it and scroll it, to the top. the google maps interface was an example. maybe that is not possible with pure css/html, but for sure with javascript, but i don't know where i can find such a solution or at least a hint

Comment: try using hammer.js . However you are asking for too many things. Pulling an element to a desired position cannot be done with pure css.

Comment: ok. thanks. but as i already said, it works fine (in that way i wanted it to work) on the computer, but not on the iphone (tested it in safari on iOS and mac). do you know why (maybe)?

Comment: no you can scroll it to the top (the blue layer). as i said it should not have the "pull" effect like in google maps, this was just an example. in the end there should be two layer (one map layer, one list layer) and the user should interact with both independently, and the list-layer can be slid over the map-layer (from top-to-bottom, or bottom-to-center, etc.)

Comment: btw thanks for the hint with hammer.js, i think this is the way to go